# Is there an *efficient* projection in mongodb that will return only the keys of a subdocument?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents, where each document contains a subdocument 'spectra'. Each entry in the 'spectra' subdocument is a large binary blob, maybe >MB.

Now, I want to generate a set of all of the unique spectra keys that appear in all of the documents of this collection. I can do this with the $objectToArray projection operator, as:

```js
db.measurements.aggregate([
  {$project: {spectra: {$map: {input: {$objectToArray: '$spectra'}, in: '$$this.k'}}}},
  {$unwind: '$spectra'},
  {$group: {_id: null, spectra: {$addToSet: '$spectra'}}
])
```

This works, but it seems that in the first projection stage, the entire sub-document must be read from the database and passed into the $map function. So I save on communication between server and client, but I still have a large I/O load on the backend.

Is my interpretation of what's happening here correct? Is there a more efficient way to get the information? I am using pymongo if there is a language-specific approach.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you mean when you request something that is 'more efficient'? There is no way for the database to read only part of a document into memory for processing today. The closest thing would be a covered query (eg an index only scan) but that doesn't sound applicable in your case? You'd have to change your schema to get the behavior that you're after (list of distinct keys) if I'm not mistaken

Comment: ... or perhaps change you data model so that `"spectra"` subfields just store a reference to, e.g., a `blobs` collection that stores the large _blobs_.

Comment: @user20042973 "There is no way for the database to read only part of a document into memory". That sounds like every time you run an `aggregate` command, the entire DB is read. That can't be true can it?  Or do you mean you can't read a partial *sub*-document?

Comment: @rickhg12hs That's a good suggestion, but probably not practical in my application for other reasons

Comment: Right, 'part of a document'  == 'partial sub-document'. Of course it's possible for the database to only process a subset of documents in a collection when it is queried, just not a subset of a subset of a document. And @rickhg12hs suggestion is the type of schema change I was thinking of.

Comment: @user20042973 would copying the sub-document keys into a separate list (at document top level) as per your original comment allow the aggregation to run without reading the large sub-document? Only if that list was also indexed?